Galaxy A14G - Camera video feedback different than captured photo
I'm developing a web app and have encountered a color discrepancy issue on A14G devices. In low-light conditions, the camera's video preview appears significantly duller than the actual captured images. For instance, a photo with four distinct green, blue, red, and light pink dots shows vibrant colors, while the video feed portrays them as muted, especially the light pink which appears completely gray. This problem persists with automatic settings enabled. However, manually adjusting the ISO improves the video preview. I've tested other phones with identical settings (ISO, shutter, white balance, etc.), but only the A14G exhibits this color inaccuracy. Has anyone else experienced this issue, and if so, how did you resolve it?
Thanks.

What kind of lighting is illuminating the subjects in your example images?

This picture was taken indoors with all the lights turned off and windows covered, and object was illuminated with whatever light was coming in through the window blinds. I have also seen this issue in a well lit room when I increase the ISO.

All lights turned off? No artificial light in the room whatsoever? No monitors, TVs, or other light emitting screens? No LED lights on computer cases, night lights/wall plugs, etc?

Yes, all the artificial lights turned off, except for a monitor in the room which was also closer to the blinds.


All the artificial lights turned off, except for a monitor in the room which was also closer to the blinds.

You may be seeing an effect from the flicker of the monitor's refresh rate.

I've noticed this same color distortion even in low light without a monitor nearby. It seems to be an issue on Motorola phones as well, and perhaps other lower-end models. Interestingly, the colors appear more accurate when I bring the object closer to the camera or zoom in.
